# Expression of $\not{p}$ in Dirac equation

Tags: momentum, conventions, dirac-matrices

In [scattering amplitudes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697), page 9, equation (2.6), (2.7), $\not{p}$ (in the Dirac equation (2.4)) is as follows:

\begin{align}
\not{p} = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & p_{a\dot{b}} \\ p^{\dot{a}b} & 0 \end{matrix} \right),
\end{align}
where $p_{a\dot{b}} =  \left( \begin{matrix} -p_0+p_3 & p_1-ip_2 \\ p_1+ip_2 & -p_0-p_3 \end{matrix} \right)$.

But on the other hand, in [the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation),
\begin{align}
\not{p} = \left( \begin{matrix} E & \sigma \cdot \vec p \\ -\sigma \cdot \vec p & -E \end{matrix} \right),
\end{align}
where $E$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. Why these two expression of $\not{p}$ are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first reference you are quoting the chiral basis with
$$\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathbf{1}_{2\times 2} \\
\mathbf{1}_{2\times 2} & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
is used while the second reference uses the (standard) Dirac basis
$$\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{1}_{2\times 2} & 0 \\
0 & -\mathbf{1}_{2\times 2}
\end{pmatrix} $$
see for example the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Other_representations).